# Lanscape mode not working in iphone with xcode 11.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios13, xcode11.4

I am trying to rotate the screen to landscape but facing issue. Now , what I am facing is when I am connected with USB for debugging it is working perfectly but , when I remove USB and then test my application then I am unable to get orientation change. I tried this on a demo application where it is working in both condition. I am sharing my method which i placed in app delegate and already choose all possible orientation in my project.

AppDelegate method :

```
 - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication )application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow )window {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with wrong orientation, wrong screen size in landscape, UITouchEvent type etc when I moved my build to xcode 11.4.
The problem was that isysroot path for linker was missing, after setting it correctly to
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk in my case all problems were gone.